# Pairs of Phrases

Tags: wordplay, english

These phrases can be put into pairs based on a rule. Find the odd one out - your answer is the one that would match it.

Before
Boyfriend or admirer
Brown or Pratt
Characteristic of Santa Claus or alcohol
Coyote's plan
Empty space between chairs
Hang around longer than necessary
It's in a can
It's in airplane bathrooms
King
Listen to
Make up for a debt
Reason
Street
Street sign with an arrow
Superman's vision
Triumphed

Comment: `Brown or Pratt` makes me think `Chris` but I can't find anything else about which I am so confident so I can't find a good match.

Comment: @Eng: Once you find the first pair it'll all fall into place.

Comment: The first pair isn't "Listen to / Reason", I guess.

Comment: @Ian: Nope, but nice find! I didn't even notice that when I was making it.

Comment: Noticed that Characteristic of Santa Claus or alcohol is only phrase out of alphabetical order. Is that a clue?

Comment: @Max: Nope, just a mistake.

Comment: Brown or Pratt could also be Whitney or Institute.

Comment: Empty Space Between Chairs / King

Comment: @zfrisch: Nope.

Comment: This is delightful!

Comment: @dennis: Thank you! Glad you liked it! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule of the pairs is that one of the words in the pair is the [Pig-Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) version of the other.

1. King / Superman's vision (Rex / X-ray)
2. Before / Make up for a debt (Pre- / Repay)
3. Triumphed / Street sign with an arrow (Won / One-Way)
4. Reason / Street (Why / Highway)
5. Lover / Listen to (Beau / Obey)
6. It's in a can / It's in an airplane bathroom (Trash / Ashtray)
7. Characteristic of Santa Claus or alcohol / Hang around longer than necessary (Stout / Outstay)
8. Coyote's plan / Empty space between chairs (Wile / Aisleway)

The odd one out is Chris (Brown or Pratt), which would match with *risqué* if a clue for that were to be included. Thanks to f'' for the last four pairs.

Comment: Three of these are right. I think you've got it - all that's left is to finish it up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still in the process. Thanks for confirming them for me, though.

Comment: Is Reason/Street another pair?

Comment: Yep! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: You can thank the book *Holes* for letting me know how to solve this.

Comment: I *thought* that might be how someone broke into the puzzle. ;)

Comment: Boyfriend or admirer (beau)/ Listen to?

Comment: It's in a can (trash)/ It's in airplane bathrooms

Comment: @f'' I thought airplanes were all smoke-free nowadays?

Comment: (That might be why I didn't get it. I had no idea "can" was referring to "trash".)

Comment: @JoeZ. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/why-do-lavatories-in-modern-planes-still-have-ash-trays

Comment: I have a better answer for #8: Characteristic of Santa Claus or alcohol (stout) / Hang around longer than necessary (outstay)

Comment: And "Empty space between chairs" pairs with "Coyote's plan" (wile), so the unpaired one is "Brown or Pratt".

Comment: Nicely done! :)